# How to run a background Intent Service immediately?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an app that needs to get XML data from a server, parse it and store it in a database. I have created an intent service for it and it works fine. But the alarmmanager does not let me call the service immediately as soon as the user logs in.

What I need is to call the service immediately at first call and have it polling in the background thereafter according to the schedule of the alarmmanager. I don't want to rewrite the same code again for the first run condition.

Is there any way to achieve this?

and code for my service is as follows.

```
public AdChangeCheckerService() {
    // Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
    super(TAG);
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    try {

        boolean isNetwork = Utility.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (isNetwork) {
            readAndStoreAds();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readAndStoreAds() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String returned = null;
    URL url = new URL(urll);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

        try {

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            InputStream in;

            if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400) {
                // Create an InputStream in order to extract the response object
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            } else {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
            }

            //converting inputstrream to string
            returned = readStream(in);

            storeAds(returned);
        } finally {
            //regardkless of success or faliure we disconnect the connection
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } else {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

}

private void storeAds(String received) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(received.getBytes());


    //setting up xml pullparser
    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();

    parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
    parser.setInput(stream, null);
    XMLParserForAds xml_parse = new XMLParserForAds(getApplicationContext());
    xml_parse.readFeedAndStore(parser);


}


private String readStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    return (result.toString());
}


public static void setServiceAlarm(Context context, boolean isOn) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, AdChangeCheckerService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (isOn) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), POLL_INTERVAL, pi);

    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(pi);
        pi.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some code for the intent service

Comment: will providing code for intent service help? i just need help for calling the intent service.

Comment: yes, it would put others in a better position to help, also more eyes on code is always a good thing - they may catch something that you missed.

Comment: ok i have done it